# CSS Hover Selector - JS or Jquery solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I've something like this:

```
<article class="leading-0">
    <h2>
        <a href="link">link title</a>
    </h2>
    <ul class="actions">
        <li class="print-icon">
            <a ...><img...></a>
        </li>
        <li class="email-icon">
            <a ...><img...></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <dl class="article-info">
        <dt class="article-info-term">...</dt>
        <dd class="hits">...</dd>
    </dl>
    <p>...</p>
</article>
```

When you hovers the `li` in `ul.tools` I want to style the `h2` element.

I would be happy if any one could help and to see if this is possible or not.

I remember doing it once before, but cant remember it.

Comment: You can't traverse / backwards with CSS selectors sadly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that you **cannot** do that with CSS only.

While you use CSS selectors to select the element, the selectors cannot select the parent element, in other words, you cannot reverse the element in any ways...

Either you can select the child element or an adjacent element using `+`

So, in your case

```
<h2><a> link </a></h2>
<ul class='tools'>
    <li> tool 1 </li>
</ul>
```

When you use `.tools li:hover`, now you cannot select any other element outside the `li`, you can select the adjacent `li` on hover of first `li` or you can select any child element to `li`.

So once you go ahead selecting elements, there is no way you can select the previous element if on the same level, nor you can select the parent element, nor you can select the adjacent element to the parent.

If you want to accomplish this, you can use Javascript or jQuery to do so.

---

As you are now open to jQuery solution, you can use

```
$("ul.actions li").hover(function(){
   $(this).parent().prev().find('a').toggleClass("hover");
});
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/2eMUy/)</kbd>

Here in the above code, am first targeting `li` using *this* keyword, than, am looking for its parent element which will select `ul`, then am using `.prev()` to look for an previous sibling element, and at the end we use `.find('a')` to target the `a` element nested inside `h2`

---

If you want the **only CSS way**, than the best thing you can do is to wrap the `h2` and `ul` in a single element, say a `div` element with a `class` say `.wrapper` than you can use a selector like

```
.wrapper:hover h2 a {
    color: red;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/cjfg6/)</kbd>

Comment: ok , but what aboutthis .tools:hover
so in your opinion this should work?
there's no difference for me hovering the ul or the li ;)

Comment: @Hossein there is a difference, if you use `.tools:hover` it will target the `ul` element, some properties would be inherited by the `li` element as well, so that's lose selector, better be specific always.

Comment: for now I will style the actual ul to be having a different alpha background collor until someone helps to find answer, but thanks for your attention ;)

Comment: @Hossein You won't get a pure CSS solution so don't wait if you are waiting for that :)

Comment: so if there was any other solutions toward this :) i'll be happy to know it :)

Comment: @Hossein Already told you in the answer, read the last line, if you retag your question to accept js or jquery answer, I will post one

Comment: @Hossein added a jQuery solution

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `+` operator,
here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/JaEGF/

```
#div1:hover + #div2{
   background:green;
}
```

Comment: OP wants to select to target the element *before* the pseudo element, which this doesn't do. This selects the next child.

Answer (score -1):

Try this CSS code:

```
article ul.tools li:hover{
    color:green;
}   
article h2 { 
    color:red;  
}
```

Comment: OP want to change the style for the `h2` element when you hover `ul.tools li` which this doesn't.

Comment: Yes, it seems we need to use jquery or JS, but still something similar to your requirement is done here..Pls check it.              http://css-tricks.com/pop-hovers/